# swap is missing from 22.04

Tags: 22.04, swap

I installed ubuntu 22.04 and there is no swap at all. In my system monitor, under resources it shows `Swap not available` I am a bit confused to be honest. Does ubuntu use swap these days, do I need to set it up myself somehow? How is this done please, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

I am also confused with the swap partition and swapfile. Which one the swap mentioned in my system moniitor refers to? Can I have swapfile set up correctly and the swap above is about swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

swap partitions are no longer required since 22.04 (maybe earlier, please correct me). Ubuntu now uses a swap file. [Is Linux swap partition still needed with Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475794/is-linux-swap-partition-still-needed-with-ubuntu-22-04) but you could probably force one if you wanted to.

Comment: I'd love to know the pros & cons of swapfile vs swap partition. Where can I learn this please?

Comment: Well it's mainly due to solid state drives being the norm' on PC's and laptops. Before SSD there was of course HDD and the pro's of using swap partitions on these disks is the ability to place them on contiguous (sectors next to one another) HDD real estate. And so it improves performance by increasing data throughput and/or decreasing seek/search time. SSD's have no such architecture and a file that can instantly change size is preferable to a permanent partitioned amount of memory.